# How to map constants to custom strings

Tags: git, rust

I am using the [git2 crate](https://docs.rs/git2/) to get a list of [statuses](https://docs.rs/git2/0.8.0/git2/struct.Status.html) on a git repository, this is the code I am using:

```
use git2::{Repository, StatusOptions, StatusShow};
use std::{collections::HashMap, env};

fn main() {
    let path = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let repo = Repository::discover(path).unwrap();
    let mut status_opt = StatusOptions::new();
    status_opt
        .show(StatusShow::IndexAndWorkdir)
        .include_untracked(true)
        .include_unmodified(false)
        .no_refresh(false);
    let status_result = repo.statuses(Some(&mut status_opt)).unwrap();

    let mut map: HashMap<git2::Status, u32> = HashMap::new();

    for status_entry in status_result.iter() {
        *map.entry(status_entry.status()).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Based on the modifications of the current repository returns a map of [`git2::Status`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.8.0/git2/struct.Status.html) and occurrences, but I would like to return a similar output to the command `git status --porcelain`.

For example, depending on the changes of the repository, this is the output of `git status --porcelain`:

```
M  file_a
AM file_b
A  file_c
?? file_e
?? file_f
```

Passing the output to `awk`:

```
$ git status --porcelain | awk -v ORS=", " 'NR>0{arr[$1]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}'
A 1, ?? 2, M 1, AM 1,
```

Using the [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org) code above will return:

```
{INDEX_NEW: 1, WT_NEW: 2, INDEX_NEW | WT_MODIFIED: 1, INDEX_MODIFIED: 1}
```

I would like to know how could I map the value of the `git2::Status` constants to custom strings (match the porceline strings), for example:

```
INDEX_NEW                -> A 
INDEX_NEW | WT_MODIFIED  -> AM
INDEX_MODIFIED           -> M
WT_NEW                   -> ??
```

Mainly how to deal with cases like `INDEX_NEW | WT_MODIFIED` that will map for example to `AM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code snippet takes your `map` and turns it into the desired representation.  The provided example collecs the values into another `HashMap` and it has an arm which panics, but feel free to convert the `git2::Status` values on the fly (i.e. when you first iterate over them).

```rust
let mut output = HashMap::new();
for (key, value) in map.iter()
{
    let key = match key
    {

        s if s.contains(git2::Status::INDEX_NEW) &&
             s.contains(git2::Status::WT_MODIFIED) => "AM",
        s if s.contains(git2::Status::INDEX_NEW) => "A",
        s if s.contains(git2::Status::INDEX_MODIFIED) => "M",
        _ => panic!("Unexpected status"),
    };

    output.insert(key, value);
}

println!("{:?}", output);
```

If you are looking into the examples of your chosen library then you will find something very similar: [`git2-rs/examples/status.rs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/git2-rs/blob/master/examples/status.rs#L262)

For further information on pattern matching syntax, consult [The Rust Programming Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html).

Comment: `s if s.contains(git2::Status::INDEX_NEW) => "A"`  since it returns a string `"A"` is because of this that can use the std::string `contains` ? also if instead of `panic` how to return as string the returend status ?

Comment: Look into the source of `git2-rs`!  If you do that, you would realise, that `git2::Status` is a `struct` generated by the macro from the [`bitflags`](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags) crate and thus it has the `.contains` method, which has nothing to do with strings.  If you don't want to panic, then replace my panicing arm with the string representation of the error of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, instead of a custom error/panic,  I would like to return for example `INDEX_NEW` or `INDEX_NEW | WT_MODIFIED` as a string so that I could get an idea of the status instead of a panic, better said how to convert a `git2::Status::INDEX_MODIFIED` to be represented as a string